# ReverseNo() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python-3.x

```
class Reverse():
    reverse = 0
    def ReverseNo(n):
        while n != 0:
            reverse = reverse*10 + n%10
            n = n//10
        return reverse        


obj1 = Reverse()
print(obj1.ReverseNo(1234))
```

It's showing me an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\christ\Desktop\python\index.py", line 13, in <module>
print(obj1.ReverseNo(1234))
Type Error: ReverseNo() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing out the `self` keyword. Your code correctly wirtten in Python...

```
class Reverse():
        
    def ReverseNo(self, n):
        reverse = 0
        while n != 0:
            reverse = reverse*10 + n%10
            n = n//10
        return reverse        


obj1 = Reverse()
print(obj1.ReverseNo(1234))
```

`self` gives your objects methods access to your objects variables & methods.